# What does "versin" mean?

Tags: trigonometry, notation, terminology

> $$\newcommand{\versin}{\operatorname{versin}}2\versin A+\cos ^2 A= 1+\versin ^2 A$$

I don't understand the word 'ver' in this equation. What does it mean?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versine

Comment: You didn't even [googled](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=versin&oq=versin&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65j69i59j69i60l3.1202j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8) before asking

Comment: I did, but I had understood it wrongly, when I stuck in this question I understood there was a mistake

Answer (score 4):

Versine is $\displaystyle1 - \cos(\theta) $  or  $ \displaystyle2\sin^2\left(\frac\theta2\right)$

'versin' is the Versine here, 'ver' by itself is nothing.

It is short for 'versed sine'.
See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versine).

Comment: Then 2versinA means 2(1-cos A)sin A?

Comment: No, it will just be 2(1-cos A)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that on the unit circle, it is the remainder of the line on the radius after the cosine is subtracted for any given angle.